# Proving that $(A \cap ((B \cap C) \cup (A^c \cap C^c)) \cup C^c= (A \cap B \cap C) \cup C^c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I currently started learning about fuzzy sets as well as operators and functions that can be applied to them. As such, I came by this question:

If $A, B, C$ are an element of $F$, then show that $$(A \cap ((B \cap C) \cup (A^c \cap C^c)) \cup C^c= (A \cap B \cap C) \cup C^c$$

I tried to prove it using the properties of fuzzy sets (ie. Distributive, Associative, etc), however, I can't seem to to prove either side is equal to the other. I am hoping someone could explain to me step by step how I would go about showing this equality? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you try to prove any of these monsters you should use a Venn diagram to check if it's correct. If it is, the diagram can lead lead you to a proof. Ii don't think there is anything fuzzy about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(A \cap ((B \cap C) \cup (A^c \cap C^c)) \cup C^c = (A \cap (((B \cap C) \cup A^c) \cap ((B \cap C) \cup C^c)) \cup C^c = (A \cap (((B \cap C) \cup A^c) \cap (B \cup C^c)) \cup C^c = (A \cap (((B \cap C)\cap(B \cup C^c)) \cup (A^c \cap(B \cup C^c)))\cup C^c= (A \cap ((B \cap C) \cup (A^c \cap (B \cup C^c)))\cup C^c= ((A \cap (B \cap C)) \cup (A \cap (A^c \cap(B \cup C^c))) \cup C^c= ((A \cap (B \cap C)) \cup \emptyset) \cup C^c = (A \cap B \cap C) \cup C^c $

Comment: Would it be possible for you tell me what u did in each step? Like what property you used to move from one to another? I am trying to decipher what was done at each step, but all its doing is making my head hurt.

Comment: I only used the fundamentals laws of set algebra. You can check them on wikipedia [link] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets). If you write and check every step carefully you will see it. 
Good luck!